# Databinding compile error with ressources

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have this error using databinding :

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
```

I try to put a color function in the binding :

```
object Colors {

    fun getGradeColor(context: Context, grade: String): Int {
        val color =  when (grade.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())) {
            "A" -> R.color.grade_a
            "B" -> R.color.grade_b
            "C" -> R.color.grade_c
            "D" -> R.color.grade_d
            else -> R.color.grade_e
        }
        return ContextCompat.getColor(context, color)
    }

}
```

This is my layout data :

```
 <data>
        <import type="androidx.core.content.ContextCompat"/>
        <variable
            name="colors"
            type="com.myapp.utils.Colors"/>
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="android.view.View.OnClickListener"/>
        <variable
            name="digitalService"
            type="com.myapp.api.response.DigitalService"/>
    </data>
```

When I use :

```
android:backgroundTint="@{colors.getGradeColor(digitalService.score.grade)}"
```

Using the compileDebugKotlin, I have this error :

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Tool version 4.5.3 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.5.3 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.7.1/Users/jerome/StudioProjects/myapp/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/myapp/DataBinderMapperImpl.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.myapp.databinding.ItemDigitalServiceBindingImpl;
```

I really don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: So when you don't set the backgroundTint you don't get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed `context` which is the first parameter of your function. You can refactor the usage of function as:

```
android:backgroundTint="@{colors.getGradeColor(context,digitalService.score.grade)}"
```

A variable named `context` is generated for use in bindings. This uses the root views context.

Comment: Didn't know about context beeing available in xml, good to know.